# Mismatched charset while executing application on Windows and Wine (Ubuntu)

Tags: windows, wine, locale, encoding, utf-8

We have a small exe client application that used for loading the scanned images from the remote sources, what we need to do is enter the address from the images to specific text box and submit. The data then will be saved in remote database and will be read by another apps.

When we run the client application on Windows, everything is normal. The problem only happen when we run application on Ubuntu via Wine: Whether we input the address that contain German characters, the other apps will read from database the wrong characters, for example:

What we enter: Lößnitzstr

What the other apps see: LÃ¶ÃŸnitzstr

Input:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Output:

[image: Screenshot 2]

We found out this is caused by a charset mismatch when encoding with UTF-8 and decode with Windows-1252 code page.

Since the default charset of Ubuntu is UTF-8, we tried to use command line to force WINE to run with Windows charset setting:

```
LANG=de_DE.CP1252 wine client.exe
```

We also tried to set the operating system default locale by localectl to language with charset Windows-1252 (CP1252) but it seems not to work

Locale:

[image: Screenshot 3]

Wine version 7.0

Ubuntu Version 20.04

Any idea how to fix this? really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello. This is a Wine and Windows app issue. Sorry this has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Did you check the Wine web site to see if this app is even supported or has any special notes.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the answers. This is our company internal apps so it was not in the wine app database. Yes, it was Wine issue but is there any other effective way to set Ubuntu environment that can force charset setting of Wine and the app running on Wine or not?